# YouTube videos are out of order?

Tags: youtube

Why is it when I view some YouTube playlists, such as [this one](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLLONuwzC-9KpMxm3kaJvFM8YugVs2ZEzq), some of the videos are out of order? How can I reorder them?

```
# 10 - 2 months ago
# 11 - 4 months ago
# 12 - 2 months ago
```

> [image]

```
# 29 - 6 months ago
# 30 - 7 months ago
# 31 - 6 months ago
```

> [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't set the order of someone else's playlist.  They can arrange the videos in the order they choose.

The dates you are pointing to  simply indicate the date a video was uploaded to YouTube. There is no requirement for the sort order to be defined by those dates unless the owner so chooses.

Given the strong correlation between the video upload dates and their order in the playlist, it is possible  they are sorted by the order they were added to the playlist.

If the current order has a negative impact, you can either:

1. Ask the owner via comment to update the sort order; or
2. Create your own playlist with their playlist's content. As owner you can then control the order.

**Note:**  If you make a copy of their playlist, your playlist will not update when they add or remove videos from theirs.

#### Instructions

1. Navigate to their playlist URL
   `https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLLONuwzC-9KpMxm3kaJvFM8YugVs2ZEzq` in your example.
2. Replace `www` in the URL with `music`
   `https://music.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLLONuwzC-9KpMxm3kaJvFM8YugVs2ZEzq`
3. Click on the three-dot menu then "Add to Playlist"
   [image]
4. Click "+ New Playlist" and give it a name.
5. Return to your YouTube library  https://www.youtube.com/feed/library and click on the "View full playlist" link of the one you just added.
6. You will now have a "Sort" menu at the top with various options including by date.
   [image]